# How to remove all white space which is by default showing in between tags

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to remove white space gap between div tags, and how to manage pixel different in between div tags. my html code is not align proper how to make align and remove white space in between div tags.

i have used this reset link but not working to remove white space between div tags

this is my css

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.phase-name {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.type-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.type-abr {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}

.type-name {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}

.phase-container input {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.phase-container {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-family: Agency-Roman;
}

.week-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.week {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.day {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
}


/****** Header row 1********/

.phase-header-1 .phase-name {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.phase-header-1 .type-container .type .week-container .week {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 546px;
}

.phase-header-1 .type .type-abr {
  background-color: #ddd;
  /*  padding:7px; */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.phase-header-1 .type .type-name {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.phase-header-1 .week {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px;
}


/****** Header row 2********/

.phase-header-2 .phase-name {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.phase-header-2 .type-name {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.phase-header-2 .type-abr {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}


/*********/

.phase-header-2 .phase-name {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px;
}

.phase-header-2 .type .type-abr {
  width: 81px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  border-color: black;
}

.phase-header-2 .type .type-name {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px;
}

.phase-header-2 .type-container .type .week-container .week .day {
  width: 106.60px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: yellow;
}


/****** Header row 3********/


/* width:43.42px; */

.phase-header-3 .week-container .week .day .reps {
  width: 43.35px;
}

.phase-header-3 .week-container .week .day .percent1 {
  width: 44px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.phase-header-3 .week-container .week .day {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.phase-header-3 .type-container .type .week-container .week .day .reps {
  display: inline-block;
}

.phase-header-3 .type-container .type .week-container .week .day .percent11 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.phase-header-3 .type .type-abr {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.phase-header-3 .type .type-name {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.phase-header-3 .phase-name {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 80px;
}


/****** Phase 1********/

.phase .type-container .day .reps {
  display: inline-block;
}

.phase .type-container .day .percent1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.phase .week-container .week .day .reps {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 39px;
}

.phase .week-container .week .day .percent1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 39px;
}

.phase .week-container .day {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 106.60px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.phase-name {
  size: 1px;
}

.phase .phase-name {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 80px;
}

.phase .type-name {
  width: 80px;
}

.type-container .type .type-abr {
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.type-container .type .type-name {
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<button class="week_button" value="">Weeks</button>
<button class="phase_button" value="">Phases</button>
<span class="paste_row_button"></span>

<div class="phases week_increase" style="overflow-x : auto; overflow-y:auto; position:relative;height: 600px;width: 100% ">
  <div class="phase-container" style="display:inline-block;width:1000%">
    <div class="phase-header-1">
      <div class="phase-name">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="type-container">
        <div class="type">
          <div class="type-abr">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="type-name">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="week-container">
            <div class="week"> Week 1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="phase-header-2">
      <div class="phase-name">PHASE</div>
      <div class="type-container">
        <div class="type">
          <div class="type-abr">ABR.</div>
          <div class="type-name">TYPE</div>
          <div class="week-container">
            <div class="week">
              <div class="day">1</div>
              <div class="day">2</div>
              <div class="day">3</div>
              <div class="day">4</div>
              <div class="day">5</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="phase-header-3" style="display:inline-block">
      <div class="phase-name">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="type-container">
        <div class="type">
          <div class="type-abr">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="type-name">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="week-container">
            <div class="week">
              <div class="day">
                <div class="reps">Reps</div>
                <div class="percent1">%</div>
              </div>
              <div class="day">
                <div class="reps">Reps</div>
                <div class="percent1">%</div>
              </div>
              <div class="day">
                <div class="reps">Reps</div>
                <div class="percent1">%</div>
              </div>
              <div class="day">
                <div class="reps">Reps</div>
                <div class="percent1">%</div>
              </div> /* there in between tags showing white space */
              <div class="day">
                <div class="reps">Reps</div>
                <div class="percent1">%</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="structure phase hide">
  <div class="phase-name">
    <input type="text" name="phase-name" />
  </div>
  <div class="type-container">
    <div class="type">
      <div class="type-abr">
        <input type="text" name="type-abr" />
      </div>
      <div class="type-name">
        <input type="text" name="type-name" />
      </div>
      <div class="week-container">
        <div class="week">
          <div class="day">
            <div class="reps">
              <input type="text" name="day1-reps" data-id="1" types="reps_value" value="location" class="name" />
            </div>
            <div class="percent1">
              <input type="text" name="day1-percent1" data-id="1" types1="reps_percent" value="location" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="day">
            <div class="reps">
              <input type="text" name="day1-reps" />
            </div>
            <div class="percent1">
              <input type="text" name="day1-percent1" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="day">
            <div class="reps">
              <input type="text" name="day1-reps" />
            </div>
            <div class="percent1">
              <input type="text" name="day1-percent1" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="day">
            <div class="reps">
              <input type="text" name="day1-reps" />
            </div>
            <div class="percent1">
              <input type="text" name="day1-percent1" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="day">
            <div class="reps">
              <input type="text" name="day1-reps" />
            </div>
            <div class="percent1">
              <input type="text" name="day1-percent1" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>






<!--jquery part-->

this is my jquery part

     $(document).on('click', '.phase_button', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.paste_row_button').append('<button class="row_button">Rows-' + ++$(".row_button").length + '</button>');
            $('.phase-container').append($(".structure").clone().removeClass("structure hide"));
        });
        $(document).on("click", ".row_button", function () {
            $(".phase").eq($(".row_button").index($(this))).css({"display": "flex", "border-left": "1px solid #ddd", "border-right": "1px solid #ddd"}).find(".type-container").append($(".structure .type").clone());
        });
        $(document).on("click", ".week_button", function () {
            console.log($(".phase-header-1 .week:first").clone());
            $(".phase-header-1 .week-container").append($(".phase-header-1 .week:first").clone());
            $(".phase-header-2 .week-container").append($(".phase-header-2 .week:first").clone());
            $(".phase-header-3 .week-container").append($(".phase-header-3 .week:first").clone());
            $(".phase").find(".week-container").append($(".structure .week:first").clone());
        });
    $(".phase_button").click();
```

this is my picture in which you can see white space which i want to remove and when i append this html structure its align not proper shows how to solve this align problem and remove whitespace.

[image]

Comment: Any reason you're trying to make your own table instead of just using a `<table>`? While they should only be used in very specific cases - this *is* one of those specific cases.

Comment: +1 to @TylerRoper, avoid using custom css, either use `table` or use css grid form  one of the popular grid css frameworks(bootstrap, foundation, ... etc).

Comment: @Tyler Roper yes sir there is reason is that i am making dynamically this structure using div tag not perfectly making dynamically this structure using <table> tags so using <div> tag instead of <table> tag you can see in my question jquery part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/658/removing-whitespaces-between-inline-block-elements-with-css

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you're using DIV's instead of a table?
This could be done very easily with a table. Here's something I threw together really quickly using tablesgenerator.com. You will obviously need to edit the styling/width of the cells more.

[Picture of table I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D63NB.png)

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-c82p{background-color:#fffe65;border-color:inherit;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-c3ow{border-color:inherit;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-4f0n{background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;border-color:inherit;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-dx7k{background-color:#656565;border-color:inherit;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-llyw{background-color:#c0c0c0;border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-llyw" colspan="2"></th>
    <th class="tg-llyw" colspan="2"></th>
    <th class="tg-llyw" colspan="2"></th>
    <th class="tg-c82p" colspan="10">Week 1</th>
    <th class="tg-c82p" colspan="4">Week 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-4f0n" colspan="2">PHASE</td>
    <td class="tg-4f0n" colspan="2">ABR</td>
    <td class="tg-4f0n" colspan="2">TYPE</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p" colspan="2">1</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p" colspan="2">2</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p" colspan="2">3</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p" colspan="2">4</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p" colspan="2">5</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p" colspan="2">1</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p" colspan="2">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-llyw" colspan="2"></td>
    <td class="tg-llyw" colspan="2"></td>
    <td class="tg-llyw" colspan="2"></td>
    <td class="tg-c82p">Reps</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p">%</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p">Reps</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p">%</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p">Reps</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p">%</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p">Reps</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p">%</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p">Reps</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p">%</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p">Reps</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p">%</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p">Reps</td>
    <td class="tg-c82p">%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-dx7k" colspan="2">Text box</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow" colspan="2">Text Box</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow" colspan="2">Text Box</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">location</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">location</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-dx7k" colspan="2"></td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow" colspan="2">Text Box</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow" colspan="2">Text Box</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">location</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">location</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-dx7k" colspan="2">Text Box</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow" colspan="2">Text Box</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow" colspan="2">Text Box</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">location</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">location</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-dx7k" colspan="2">Text Box</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow" colspan="2">Text Box</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow" colspan="2">Text Box</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">location</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">location</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-dx7k" colspan="2"></td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow" colspan="2">Text Box</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow" colspan="2">Text Box</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">location</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">location</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sir, as possible using <div> tag you can solve i avoid to use td tr tags and sir Resionto not use <table> tag is i am making dynamically this structure its not working with <table> tag

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left` for the `div`s that were one after another.

Or use bootstrap column classes for grid ->  https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Try this.

working codepen example: -> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VEXKJe

```js
 $(document).on('click', '.phase_button', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('.paste_row_button').append('<button class="row_button">Rows-' + ++$(".row_button").length + '</button>');
                $('.phase-container').append($(".structure").clone().removeClass("structure hide"));
            });
            $(document).on("click", ".row_button", function () {
                $(".phase").eq($(".row_button").index($(this))).css({"display": "flex", "border-left": "1px solid #ddd", "border-right": "1px solid #ddd"}).find(".type-container").append($(".structure .type").clone());
            });
            $(document).on("click", ".week_button", function () {
                console.log($(".phase-header-1 .week:first").clone());
                $(".phase-header-1 .week-container").append($(".phase-header-1 .week:first").clone());
                $(".phase-header-2 .week-container").append($(".phase-header-2 .week:first").clone());
                $(".phase-header-3 .week-container").append($(".phase-header-3 .week:first").clone());
                $(".phase").find(".week-container").append($(".structure .week:first").clone());
            });
        $(".phase_button").click();
```

```css
    * {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
   .week .day{float:left;}
   .week .day .reps{float:left;}
    .phase-name {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 80px;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 7px;
      vertical-align: top;
    }

    .type-container {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .type-abr {
      width: 80px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 7px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .type-name {
      width: 80px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 7px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .phase-container input {
      max-width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .phase-container {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      font-family: Agency-Roman;
    }

.week-container {
      float:left;
     display:flex;
    }

    .week {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .day {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 7px;width:107.3px;
    }


    /****** Header row 1********/

    .phase-header-1 .phase-name {
      background-color: #ddd;
      padding: 7px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      float:left;
    }

    .phase-header-1 .type-container .type .week-container .week {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      width: 600px;
    }

    .phase-header-1 .type .type-abr {
      background-color: #ddd;
      /*  padding:7px; */
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    .phase-header-1 .type .type-name {
      background-color: #ddd;
      padding: 7px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      float:left;
    }

    .phase-header-1 .week {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: yellow;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 7px;
    }


    /****** Header row 2********/

    .phase-header-2 .phase-name {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }

    .phase-header-2 .type-name {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      margin-left: -1px;
    }

    .phase-header-2 .type-abr {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }


    /*********/

    .phase-header-2 .phase-name {
      width: 85px;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 7px;
      float:left;
    }

    .phase-header-2 .type .type-abr {
      width: 81px;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 7px;
      margin-left: 0px;
      border-color: black;
      float:left;
    }

    .phase-header-2 .type .type-name {
      width: 80px;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 7px;
      float:left;
    }

    .phase-header-2 .type-container .type .week-container .week .day {
      width: 106.60px;
      border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
      background-color: yellow;
    }


    /****** Header row 3********/


    /* width:43.42px; */

    .phase-header-3 .week-container .week .day .reps {
      width: 43.35px;
    }

    .phase-header-3 .week-container .week .day .percent1 {
      width: 44px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .phase-header-3 .week-container .week .day {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    .phase-header-3 .type-container .type .week-container .week .day .reps {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .phase-header-3 .type-container .type .week-container .week .day .percent11 {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .phase-header-3 .type .type-abr {
      background-color: #ddd;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    .phase-header-3 .type .type-name {
      background-color: #ddd;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    .phase-header-3 .phase-name {
      background-color: #ddd;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      width: 80px;
      float:left;
    }



    /****** Phase 1********/

    .phase .type-container .day .reps {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .phase .type-container .day .percent1 {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .phase .week-container .week .day .reps {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 39px;
    }

    .phase .week-container .week .day .percent1 {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 39px;
    }
     
    .phase .week-container .day {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #ddd;
      width: 106.60px;
      padding: 7px;
    }

    .phase-name {
      size: 1px;
    }

    .phase .phase-name {
      background-color: gray;
      width: 80px;
    }

    .phase .type-name {
      width: 80px;
    }

    .type-container .type .type-abr {
      border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
      float:left;
    }

    .type-container .type .type-name {
      border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
      float:left;
    }
```

```html
 <button class="week_button" value="">Weeks</button>
    <button class="phase_button" value="">Phases</button>
    <span class="paste_row_button"></span>

    <div class="phases week_increase" style="overflow-x : auto; overflow-y:auto; position:relative;height: 600px;width: 100% ">
      <div class="phase-container" style="display:inline-block;width:1000%">
        <div class="phase-header-1">
          <div class="phase-name">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="type-container">
            <div class="type">
              <div class="type-abr">&nbsp;</div>
              <div class="type-name">&nbsp;</div>
              <div class="week-container">
                <div class="week"> Week 1</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="phase-header-2">
          <div class="phase-name">PHASE</div>
          <div class="type-container">
            <div class="type">
              <div class="type-abr">ABR.</div>
              <div class="type-name">TYPE</div>
              <div class="week-container">
                <div class="week">
                  <div class="day">1</div>
                  <div class="day">2</div>
                  <div class="day">3</div>
                  <div class="day">4</div>
                  <div class="day">5</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="phase-header-3" style="display:inline-block">
          <div class="phase-name">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="type-container">
            <div class="type">
              <div class="type-abr">&nbsp;</div>
              <div class="type-name">&nbsp;</div>
              <div class="week-container">
                <div class="week">
                  <div class="day">
                    <div class="reps">Reps</div>
                    <div class="percent1">%</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="day">
                    <div class="reps">Reps</div>
                    <div class="percent1">%</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="day">
                    <div class="reps">Reps</div>
                    <div class="percent1">%</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="day">
                    <div class="reps">Reps</div>
                    <div class="percent1">%</div>
                  </div> /* there in between tags showing white space */
                  <div class="day">
                    <div class="reps">Reps</div>
                    <div class="percent1">%</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="structure phase hide">
      <div class="phase-name">
        <input type="text" name="phase-name" />
      </div>
      <div class="type-container">
        <div class="type">
          <div class="type-abr">
            <input type="text" name="type-abr" />
          </div>
          <div class="type-name">
            <input type="text" name="type-name" />
          </div>
          <div class="week-container">
            <div class="week">
              <div class="day">
                <div class="reps">
                  <input type="text" name="day1-reps" data-id="1" types="reps_value" value="location" class="name" />
                </div>
                <div class="percent1">
                  <input type="text" name="day1-percent1" data-id="1" types1="reps_percent" value="location" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="day">
                <div class="reps">
                  <input type="text" name="day1-reps" />
                </div>
                <div class="percent1">
                  <input type="text" name="day1-percent1" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="day">
                <div class="reps">
                  <input type="text" name="day1-reps" />
                </div>
                <div class="percent1">
                  <input type="text" name="day1-percent1" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="day">
                <div class="reps">
                  <input type="text" name="day1-reps" />
                </div>
                <div class="percent1">
                  <input type="text" name="day1-percent1" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="day">
                <div class="reps">
                  <input type="text" name="day1-reps" />
                </div>
                <div class="percent1">
                  <input type="text" name="day1-percent1" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: sir, there is white space in between week and in its days,sir when you runs  code you can also append new user input text this user input text is not in align in my code